# Error when using React.js and the Twilio API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twilio

I'm investigating creating a small Twilio app for a project using React.js. I'm fairly good at React and JavaScript (but not an expert), but I'm having a bit of trouble.

Initially, I am trying to load all the messages on the account to the webpage. Here is the code I have:

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

var accountSid = '####';
var authToken = "####";
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

var msgList = []

const messages = () => {
  client.messages.list(function(err, data) {
    data.messages.forEach(function(message) {
      msgList.push(message)
    });
  })
  return msgList
}

class LandingPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello!</h1>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(select)(LandingPage)
```

(of course, there are more files, but this is my current working file where I am having the issues).

First of all, when I load this up in my browser, I get an error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: querystring.unescape is not a function
```

This apparently relates to the `client.messages.list(function(err, data) {` line.

Also, how would I go about rendering each `message.body`? I guess I would have to use a `for` loop but I'm not sure where that would go here.

Answer (score 3):

The library you are trying to use was written for Node.js, and I assume you're trying to use it in the browser or in React Native? A couple bits:

- You shouldn't use the Twilio API from a client side application with your account SID and auth token. These credentials are the "keys to the kingdom" for your Twilio account, and can be compromised if you put them in any client-side app.
- The module you are trying to use was written for Node.js, and may not work out of the box in the browser. I haven't tested it, but it might work with Browserify if you were to package your front-end code that way.

For the use case you're trying to implement, I would fetch the messages on your server, and send them to the client via Ajax rather than hitting the API directly from the client.

Comment: Hey Kevin, thanks for the advice! I knew about the security issues regarding the SID and auth token but wasn't sure how to address them so I'll have a look into using Node and Ajax, thanks. Also it hadn't occurred to me that the Twilio code I was using was for Node so would have to be in a Node environment. So thanks, I'll look into using Browserify :)